# Hitting probabilities in a random walk on a graph

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a random walk $(X_n)$ on the graph below, where we jump from a given vertex to one of its adjacent vertices with equal probability. I want to find:

- the probability that we hit $A$ before hitting $F$, given that $X_0=B$
- the expected first passage time from $B$ to $F$ without hitting $A$.

[image]

**Thoughts**

I thought it might help to modify the state space into $A,X,Y,F$ where $X=\{B,C\}$ and $Y=\{E,D\}$ (I did not clump all four together because getting to $A$ from $B$ is different to getting there from $E$ or $D$).

With some help from the comments, I get the following transition matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac13 & \frac13 & \frac13 & 0\\ 0 & \frac13 & \frac13 & \frac13\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
(states in order $A,X,Y,F$). So we want:
$$\mathbb{P}_B(\text{hit}\,A\,\text{before}\,H)=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb{P}_B\left(X_k=A\bigcap_{m<k} X_m\neq A,F\right)$$
But I'm stuck on how to evaluate this? It feels like I'm using the wrong method altogether.

Comment: When one can fuse some states as you did, the resulting transitions from fused state $U$ to fused state $V$ is $\bar p_{U,V}=\sum\limits_{v\in V}p_{u,v}$ for every $u$ in $U$. In your case, one gets for example $\bar p_{X,X}=p_{B,C}=\frac13$ and $\bar p_{A,X}=p_{A,B}+p_{A,C}=1$.

Comment: I'm confused why you are modifying the state space in this way. My initial thought is that, for the sort of questions you're asking, one would remove vertices from the state space and then use the (non-stochastic) transition matrix for calculations.

Comment: @Did Thanks. So I can fix any $u\in U$ and $\sum_v p_{u,v}=p_{U,V}$? Why this value does not depend on $u$ though, it feels like it should?

Comment: When it does depend on $u$ in $U$, the lumped process may not be a Markov chain. When $\sum\limits_vp_{u,v}$ depends on $u$ only through the lumped state $U$ that $u$ belongs to, the lumped process is a Markov chain (with transition probabilities $\bar p$). "Lumped process" is the official name. Since the condition holds in your setting, what remains to solve the question you ask is to write down the transitions $\bar p$ on the state space $\{A,X,Y,F\}$ and to study the $\bar p$ lumped process.